# Test identicality of discrete distributions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, discrete-data

Is there a standard way to test whether two vectors were drawn with the same **discrete** distribution in R? Something like a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but for discrete distributions.

I think two-sample chi-squared test would be appropriate. Does any package provide it? I can't get `chisq.test` to work for me.

Comment: Not an `R` question

Comment: There are two different questions, really. The first is how to do that, and the second is how to do that in R. The first question is better suited on CrossValidated, and the second is too broad without the exact algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps the second part i.e. the my guess on how to perform such a test is not important and can be removed. Main question is: is there a standard test ready for use in R? I guess there are many ways to test the condition. I'm only interested in those available in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and distributions that aren't continuous is that the possible permutations of the observations are not all equally likely, so the null distribution of the test statistic doesn't apply.

Indeed it's no longer distribution-free, and using the test "as is" is generally quite conservative (has a substantially lower type I error rate than the nominal rate - and correspondingly lower power).

One possibility is to use the statistic but actually compute the permutation distribution (in small samples) or sample from it (a randomization test).

The chi-square test tends to have low power against interesting alternatives because it ignores ordering. Smooth tests of goodness of fit (which in the simplest case can be treated as a partitioning of the chi-square into low-order components and an untested residual) don't ignore the ordering and tend to have better power. See, for example, the books by Rayner and Best (and others, in some cases).

---

To get the chi-square to work (though with ordered data I wouldn't do it this way, as I mentioned) you'll need to present it as a two-row (or -column) table of counts:

```
value:   0  1  2  3  4  5 
    X:   4  7  9  3  1  1 
    Y:   0  2  5  6 12  5
```

What you are doing is a test of homogeneity of proportions. For the chi-square, which conditions on both margins, this is identical to a test of independence.

So for this data frame, which I have called `xycnt`:

```
  x  y
0 4  0
1 7  2
2 9  5
3 3  6
4 1 12
5 1  5
```

we just do this:

```
> chisq.test(xycnt)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  xycnt
X-squared = 20.6108, df = 5, p-value = 0.0009593

Warning message:
In chisq.test(xycnt) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

In this case it complains because the expected counts in some cells are small. One solution is not to rely on the chi-square approximation to the test statistic but to simulate its distribution, obtaining a simulated p-value:

```
chisq.test(xycnt,simulate.p.value=TRUE,B=100000)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 1e+05 replicates)

data:  xycnt
X-squared = 20.6108, df = NA, p-value = 0.00032
```

With such a small p-value, simulated estimates of it are a bit variable, but always small. You can always up the number of simulations further, it's pretty fast. (Ten million simulations generally give p-values between 0.00032 and 0.00033 and only take a few seconds)

Comment: How does this compare to a Fisher exact test? I am aware of some of the drawbacks of the Fisher exact test, but I'm curious  which way is more proper statistically speaking.

Comment: The Fisher exact test has the same issues as the chi-squared test in that it ignores ordering of categories (and so will have low power against "smooth" alternatives which are often of greatest interest). While I expect the power of the chi-squared and the Fisher exact test to be close, the Fisher exact test might do slightly better than the chi-squared in cases like this (or it might not -- it would be possible to investigate), but they're both wasting potentially important information so its probably not important whether one is slightly better for this situation and sample size.

Comment: @Glen_b Is there any method consider the order?

Comment: Yes; for example there's Smooth Tests of Goodness of Fit. Or you could use say a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, say. Or indeed a number of other possible options.

Answer (score -3):

Doing a google search for 'Kolmogorov-Smirnov test using R' shows a 'ks.test( ...
in the stat package (a default package).  Don't know about the discrete part, but you can read through and see if it applies to your project.

Comment: Please read Wikipedia entry on Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to learn about "the discrete part". To my understanding KS is not applicable here.