# Pearson's $\chi^{2}$ value?

Tags: chi-squared-test

Pearson's $\chi^{2}$ value is 115.778 and 4 cells (33.33%) have expected count has less than 5. I am confused how to interpret this output. I have a 2 by 6 contingency table. Can someone tell me what has gone wrong?

Comment: You may want to post the contingency table or more information to get a specific answer.  Your question is quite vague.

Comment: @Underminer Nevertheless it is objectively answerable, because the result is so clear.

Comment: Is there some reason to believe something has gone wrong? I see no reason to believe that you couldn't get that chi-squared value for a 2x6 table where 4 cells have expected counts <5. Also, be aware that the <5 rule is overly cautious, so the analysis *can* be fine sometimes even when that's true. Can you say more about your situation, your data, your goals & your results here?

Comment: Arpit could you include the output that concerns you, and perhaps even the table of counts, and explain why you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you say something has 'gone wrong'? Everything looks fine there to me.

The usual "expected greater than 5" rule of thumb (well over 60 years old now, I believe) is too strict. But if you have a number of values with expected around 1 or less, especially if all the expected values aren't close to equal, then you may have some cause to worry about using the chi-square approximation.

Even so, while the chi-square approximation to the distribution of the test statistic under the null may not be terribly close to the actual (discrete) distribution, it simply means that your p-value won't be as accurate as we might like.

It would be possible to get an accurate p-value via simulation (this is simple in R for example, where it's built into the `chisq.test` function).

[There's an example of me using this facility [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113692/test-identicality-of-discrete-distribution/113708#113708) - done first using the chi-square approximation, which gave a p-value of 0.00096 and then using simulation, which gave a p-value of 0.00032. In your case, I think your p-values will be much lower still.]

Nevertheless, it's not particularly necessary because your chi-square value is *so large*; if your significance level is any of the common ones (like 5% or 1% say, or even a good deal smaller), you'd still reject the null very comfortably.

I think the only reason to bother computing an accurate p-value would be to appease some journal editor or something like that. Unless it's reasonably easy for you to obtain the simulated distribution of the test statistic (or a simulated p-value) I'd be saying "the null is obviously rejected, we're done".

Comment: So you're saying the textbook rule is incorrect? And we ignore it unless we have a statistic that could be rejected or not rejected?

Comment: "Incorrect" is too strong a word; we're talking about opinions about how good an approximation is. There have been many papers (4 or 5 at least) since that have said that it's overly strict and suggested less stringent approaches. *Your mileage may vary*. But at some point you will encounter cases where the chi-square approximation is really not good. My answer gives suggestions about what to do then.