# Chi-squared test, Poisson distribution, type I error overestimated - well-suited test for discrete distributions?

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, hypothesis-testing

**UPDATE** I edited my original question to make it as clear as  possible.

My goal is to find a reliable goodness-of-fit test for Poisson-distributed samples. There are a few discussions here related to goodness-of-fit tests for discrete distributions, e.g., the Poisson distribution (for example, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55148/goodness-of-fit-to-poisson-distribution) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113692/test-identicality-of-discrete-distributions)). I have created a simulation to understand what happens to the type I error in the case of the chi-squared test. I am working with a sum of Poisson-distributed variables (which is in turn a Poisson-distributed variable itself):

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 100000
alpha <- 0.05 # significance level
n_sim <- 10
res_chi2 <- vector(mode = "list", length = n_sim)
res_ks <- vector(mode = "list", length = n_sim)

lambda_i <- 10^sample(-10:-2, 100, replace = TRUE) # 100 Poisson-distributed variables
total_lambda <- sum(lambda_i) # the random variable of interest is a sum of Poisson-distributed variables

for (i in 1:n_sim){
  set.seed(i)
  
  # observed frequencies
  my_sample <- rowSums(sapply(lambda_i, function(x) rpois(n, x))) # generate a sample by aggregating event counts of subsamples
  sample_freq <- table(my_sample)
  
  # expected frequencies
  # calculated using the density function for the aggregate Poisson distribution
  theor_freq <- dpois(as.numeric(names(sample_freq)), total_lambda)*n
  # add missing count for (n,+ inf) to the last bin
  # now frequencies are normalized to n (sample size)
  theor_freq[length(theor_freq)] <- theor_freq[length(theor_freq)] + n - sum(theor_freq)
  
  # test statistic, the first formula below
  #  https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35f.htm
  test_statistic <- sum((theor_freq - sample_freq)^2/theor_freq)
  # no estimated parameters, df = number of categories - 1
  p_value <- 1 - pchisq(test_statistic, df = length(theor_freq)-1)
  # if TRUE, the null is accepted
  res_chi2[[i]] <- p_value >= alpha
}

sum_passed_chi2 <- Reduce(`+`,res_chi2)


# 1000 simulations
> 1000 - sum_passed_chi2
> 92
# the null was rejected 92 times
```

The type I error is equal to 9% for the chi-squared test. *Why is it overestimated?* Can I assume that a well-suited goodness-of-fit test will give an error of approximately 5% (my significance level)? **How do I implement/design a proper goodness-of-fit to test whether a sample is distributed according to a Poisson distribution with known parameters?**

**UPDATE 2** I also ran a simulation with a single sample drawn from a Poisson distribution, i.e.:

```
my_sample <- rpois(n, total_lambda)
```

In this case, the type I error rate is 8%.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing a valid, well-tested implementation of a chi-squared test here.  Consider the possibility of bugs in your program.

Comment: @whuber thanks for looking at my question. I am polishing it and will sumbit an edited  version of the question with well-documented code shortly

Comment: Another possibility is that you appear to be applying the chi-squared test to data where it's known to be invalid.  In particular, if I'm reading your code correctly, you are generating datasets with incredibly low Poisson parameters, which in many cases (despite the large `n`) will generate a lot of zeros, a few ones, and (very rarely) anything larger.

Comment: @whuber What are circumstances in which the chi-squared test is known to be invalid? My simulation is based on a practical problem where one deals with a bunch of random variables, some of which may have low Poisson parameters (the rate lambda is such that an event may or may not happen during the simulation, e.g.,  0.001 and simulation size is for example 100). The sum of such variables is Poisson-distributed, and one can calculate its total rate. I am trying to find a robust test, and most well-known tests seem to be not suited here (e.g. the KS test has a continuity requirement)

Comment: The chi-squared test is invalid when there is a small number of bins and an appreciable proportion of the expected counts in those bins are small; when the bins are constructed based on the data themselves; or when the parameter estimates are not MLEs based on the counts.  For details see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I thoroughly read your post. In my understanding, it mostly deals with a situation when "the parameter estimates are not MLEs based on the counts". This is not applicable in my case as the reference distribution is know appriori. Would you please elaborate on "the bins are constructed based on the data themselves"? What does this really mean? Does this also mean (if I understand it right) that the accepted answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92627/how-to-use-the-chi-squared-test-to-determine-if-data-follow-the-poisson-distribu) is not actually correct?

Comment: Your comment contradicts your code.  For instance, `df = length(theor_freq)-1` indicates you have *estimated* the reference distribution, for otherwise you wouldn't subtract the $1.$  The bins have to be specified without seeing the data.  This precludes, for instance, combining bins with small counts in order to create a bin with an acceptably large expected count. Many of your issues would be resolved by conducting suitable unit tests of your code to check that it correctly implements a chi-squared test.

Comment: The number of df is `length(theor_freq)-1` because the number of counts is constrained. Every single implementation of the chi-squared test I checked states that `df = k - c`, where `c` is the number of estimated parameters *plus one*, i.e. 0+1=1 in my case. I tested my code, and it returns the same values as `chisq.test` in R when I provide my data on input. A separate question is whether binning is correct (as you pointed out). Most implemented chi-squared tests  for Poisson I checked use sample observations to create bins. This is not allowed and is not correct. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Typically using the sample observations to create bins creates little harm because there are many bins and the result is insensitive to the choice.  In your case, where there are a tiny number of bins and most have tiny expected counts, the result likely is sensitive to that choice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My final question. As far as I understand, using the sample observations to create bins means that we cannot the chi-square distribution to approximate the test statistic. Can one circumvent this problem by using a Monte-Carlo simulation to estimate the statistic distribution (i.e., p-values) for a given bin choice?

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, the standard function `chisq.test` in `R` offers that as an option.  I tend to circumvent the problem by using the specified (null) distribution to determine the bins. For instance, I will group all extreme counts into a bin with an expected count of around 5.  This is perfectly legitimate because it isn't based on the *data,* it's based only on the hypothesis.